# Etherrum geth command shows "retrieved hash chain is invalid" in windows 10 powershell

Tags: ethereum, go-ethereum

While running geth command on powershell, I am getting Error :

> "WARN [02-19|02:44:45] Synchronisation failed, dropping peer
>   peer=5dac192c404506a0 err="retrieved hash chain is invalid"

**And after that no more node packets are downloaded.**

Can someone help me on how to resolve the issue ?

Following is complete powershell terminal trace

PS C:\Users\pidaftar\Desktop\Etherum> geth upgradedb
INFO [02-19|02:43:20] Maximum peer count                       ETH=25 LES=0 total=25
INFO [02-19|02:43:20] Starting peer-to-peer node               instance=Geth/v1.8.0-stable-5f540757/windows-amd64/go1.9.2
INFO [02-19|02:43:20] Allocated cache and file handles         database=C:\Users\pidaftar\AppData\Roaming\Ethereum\geth\chaindata cache=768 handles=1024
INFO [02-19|02:43:20] Writing default main-net genesis block
INFO [02-19|02:43:20] Persisted trie from memory database      nodes=12356 size=2.34mB time=46.2127ms gcnodes=0 gcsize=0.00B gctime=0s livenodes=1 livesize=0.00B
INFO [02-19|02:43:21] Initialised chain configuration          config="{ChainID: 1 Homestead: 1150000 DAO: 1920000 DAOSupport: true EIP150: 2463000 EIP155: 2675000 EIP158: 2675000 Byzantium: 4370000 Engine: ethash}"
INFO [02-19|02:43:21] Disk storage enabled for ethash caches   dir=C:\Users\pidaftar\AppData\Roaming\Ethereum\geth\ethash count=3
INFO [02-19|02:43:21] Disk storage enabled for ethash DAGs     dir=C:\Users\pidaftar\AppData\Ethash                          count=2
INFO [02-19|02:43:21] Initialising Ethereum protocol           versions="[63 62]" network=1
INFO [02-19|02:43:21] Loaded most recent local header          number=0 hash=d4e567…cb8fa3 td=17179869184
INFO [02-19|02:43:21] Loaded most recent local full block      number=0 hash=d4e567…cb8fa3 td=17179869184
INFO [02-19|02:43:21] Loaded most recent local fast block      number=0 hash=d4e567…cb8fa3 td=17179869184
INFO [02-19|02:43:21] Loaded local transaction journal         transactions=0 dropped=0
INFO [02-19|02:43:21] Regenerated local transaction journal    transactions=0 accounts=0
INFO [02-19|02:43:21] Starting P2P networking
INFO [02-19|02:43:23] Mapped network port                      proto=udp extport=30303 intport=30303 interface="UPNP IGDv1-IP1"
INFO [02-19|02:43:23] UDP listener up                          self=enode://dc2817740e8fe1897dc30e0ddfec88ef4ad318de35debf3ea9c16c51498e4ed99fb19358496b99bbf5b4ed13f869b555a058191ad1b16f5a7636130f80006220@10.119.44.55:30303
INFO [02-19|02:43:23] RLPx listener up                         self=enode://dc2817740e8fe1897dc30e0ddfec88ef4ad318de35debf3ea9c16c51498e4ed99fb19358496b99bbf5b4ed13f869b555a058191ad1b16f5a7636130f80006220@10.119.44.55:30303
INFO [02-19|02:43:23] IPC endpoint opened                      url=\\.\pipe\geth.ipc
INFO [02-19|02:43:23] Mapped network port                      proto=tcp extport=30303 intport=30303 interface="UPNP IGDv1-IP1"
INFO [02-19|02:43:33] Block synchronisation started
INFO [02-19|02:43:35] Imported new state entries               count=230 elapsed=0s processed=230 pending=3681 retry=0 duplicate=0 unexpected=0
INFO [02-19|02:43:35] Imported new block headers               count=192 elapsed=1.116s number=192 hash=723899…123390 ignored=0
INFO [02-19|02:43:35] Imported new block receipts              count=2   elapsed=0s     number=2   hash=b495a1…4698c9 size=8.00B  ignored=0
INFO [02-19|02:43:35] Imported new block headers               count=192 elapsed=29.615ms number=384 hash=d3d5d5…c79cf3 ignored=0
INFO [02-19|02:43:41] Imported new state entries               count=384 elapsed=0s       processed=614 pending=9825 retry=0 duplicate=0 unexpected=0
INFO [02-19|02:43:41] Imported new block receipts              count=2   elapsed=0s       number=4   hash=23adf5…3cd3a2 size=1.09kB ignored=0
INFO [02-19|02:43:41] Imported new block receipts              count=2   elapsed=0s       number=6   hash=1f1aed…6b326e size=8.00B  ignored=0
INFO [02-19|02:43:41] Imported new block headers               count=384 elapsed=107.302ms number=768 hash=5cfe57…c19c3a ignored=0
INFO [02-19|02:43:51] Imported new block receipts              count=15  elapsed=2.515ms   number=21  hash=b8de27…13a8a2 size=1.13kB ignored=0
INFO [02-19|02:43:51] Imported new block receipts              count=11  elapsed=1.002ms   number=32  hash=88be69…60ae13 size=44.00B ignored=0
INFO [02-19|02:43:51] Imported new block headers               count=192 elapsed=82.794ms  number=960 hash=916910…1d0e2a ignored=0
INFO [02-19|02:44:01] Imported new state entries               count=768 elapsed=0s        processed=1382 pending=12363 retry=0 duplicate=0 unexpected=0
INFO [02-19|02:44:01] Imported new block receipts              count=4   elapsed=509.8µs   number=36  hash=5f81bf…8cbf9a size=1.09kB ignored=0
INFO [02-19|02:44:01] Imported new block headers               count=192 elapsed=86.236ms  number=1152 hash=495b33…0fc327 ignored=0
INFO [02-19|02:44:11] Imported new block receipts              count=19  elapsed=1.002ms   number=55   hash=eb5889…c935f9 size=1.16kB ignored=0
INFO [02-19|02:44:11] Imported new block headers               count=192 elapsed=100.279ms number=1344 hash=84b787…0e2783 ignored=0
INFO [02-19|02:44:21] Imported new state entries               count=768 elapsed=8.020ms   processed=2150 pending=11923 retry=0 duplicate=0 unexpected=0
INFO [02-19|02:44:21] Imported new block receipts              count=8   elapsed=992.7µs   number=63   hash=c27686…f8b2ba size=1.10kB ignored=0
INFO [02-19|02:44:21] Imported new block receipts              count=2   elapsed=1.001ms   number=65   hash=35209c…d130dd size=8.00B  ignored=0
INFO [02-19|02:44:21] Imported new block headers               count=192 elapsed=97.855ms  number=1536 hash=b787b8…7d0da3 ignored=0
INFO [02-19|02:44:31] Imported new block receipts              count=6   elapsed=0s        number=71   hash=c7553e…aad92b size=1.10kB ignored=0
INFO [02-19|02:44:31] Imported new block receipts              count=4   elapsed=0s        number=75   hash=6bf173…b5f799 size=16.00B ignored=0
INFO [02-19|02:44:31] Imported new block headers               count=192 elapsed=45.119ms  number=1728 hash=d8c37e…b4f264 ignored=0
INFO [02-19|02:44:41] Imported new block receipts              count=7   elapsed=2.006ms   number=82   hash=861461…3f3d8c size=1.10kB ignored=0
INFO [02-19|02:44:41] Imported new block receipts              count=11  elapsed=2.000ms   number=93   hash=fd07e3…10ab8b size=1.12kB ignored=0
INFO [02-19|02:44:41] Imported new block headers               count=192 elapsed=38.141ms  number=1920 hash=80013e…3549c2 ignored=0
WARN [02-19|02:44:45] Rolled back headers                      count=1920 header=1920->0 fast=93->0 block=0->0
WARN [02-19|02:44:45] Synchronisation failed, dropping peer    peer=5dac192c404506a0 err="retrieved hash chain is invalid"

Answer (score 0):

Maybe i will not help you to solve this particular problem but i encountered in similar problem on Windows 10 when i was running **geth syncmode fast**.
*geth --testnet --syncmode "fast" --rpc --rpcapi db,eth,net,web3,personal --cache=1024 --rpcport 8545 --rpcaddr 127.0.0.1 --rpccorsdomain "*"*

Basically on some moment process was giving me similar messages and geth process in windows was raising up to 9GB of memory that was following to whole process fail with fatal out of memory message.

I removed entire DB and run sync in CMD, not in powershel. After that i did not have such problems.

Comment: Actually i think this message is regular message that you may receive. In my case, the process was stuck all the time.